# How to use ::before to make a shadow on top of a div with an image

Tags: html, css

I have this small image and i want to repeat so that it looks like a shadow on top of my div that it's like a cookies notification. How can i position it on top of my div cookieConsent like a shadow on the top?

THE IMAGE: [image: shadow]

```css
#cookieConsent {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #474540F2;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.cookieContainer {
  padding: 16px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 16px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.cookieConsent-txt {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  width: calc (100% - 101px);
  margin: 0;
}

#cookieConsent a.cookieConsentOK {
  width: 85px;
  height: 56px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="cookieConsent">
  <div class="cookieContainer">
    <p class="cookieConsent-txt">
      This site uses cookies
    </p>
    <a class="cookieConsentOK">Aceitar Cookies</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you not using CSS shadows? https://www.w3schools.com/csS/css3_shadows_box.asp

Comment: @kitswas cause i'll use this cookies notification on a website and i don't want the shadow at the bottom, left and right

Comment: Unrelated: are you trying to spoof a cookie consent? That's a huge problem unless you are actively stopping data collection before someone clicks the "Aceitar Cookies" button. If you aren't stopping data collection before someone clicks that, you are opening yourself up to potential legal issues.

Comment: @disinfor It will be stopping date collection! Im just doing the frontend but the backend will be done correctly by experienced people

Comment: @julia great! Also, if you rollback a question's edit, don't remove the snippet. Snippets are a way for us to test your code. I added two ways to do what you're asking below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use an image for this, you can use the `box-shadow` properties and negative values - specifically the `y` and `spread` properties.

```css
#cookieConsent {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #474540F2;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  box-shadow: 0px -4px 10px -2px rgb(0, 0, 0,0.4);
}

.cookieContainer {
  padding: 16px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 16px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.cookieConsent-txt {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  width: calc (100% - 101px);
  margin: 0;
}

#cookieConsent a.cookieConsentOK {
  width: 85px;
  height: 56px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="cookieConsent">
  <div class="cookieContainer">
    <p class="cookieConsent-txt">
      This site uses cookies
    </p>
    <a class="cookieConsentOK">Aceitar Cookies</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you need to use an image, set the image as a background on a pseudo element:

```
#cookieConsent::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/10);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -10px;
}
```

```css
#cookieConsent {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #474540F2;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
}

#cookieConsent::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/10);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -10px;
}

.cookieContainer {
  padding: 16px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 16px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.cookieConsent-txt {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  width: calc (100% - 101px);
  margin: 0;
}

#cookieConsent a.cookieConsentOK {
  width: 85px;
  height: 56px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="cookieConsent">
  <div class="cookieContainer">
    <p class="cookieConsent-txt">
      This site uses cookies
    </p>
    <a class="cookieConsentOK">Aceitar Cookies</a>
  </div>
</div>
```